# CreditCart payment for 1 fixed product (no PayPal, no Google Checkout, no Ubercart)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, paypal, credit-card, ubercart

I'm about to start a new Drupal website. My client needs CreditCart payment (in-site with authorize.net). So he doesn't want PayPal or Google Checkout through Credit Cart payment. As I know Ubercart is well working solution. but i have 1 fixed product. I don't need any shopping basket, etc. so Ubercart is too big for my need. I just need simply CC payment. Is there any smaller alternative to Ubercart for this purpose? what would you recommend?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Will the cost for this product be variable (eg depending on any attribute selections) or include additional variable costs such as shipping? Or will there be 1 single cost for all users with no possible exceptions?

Comment: Also, I'd be inclinde NOT to tag this as an Ubercart / Paypal question if you have ruled these out.

Comment: thanks for your time Citrus. Cost is fixed 1 price. no additional detail that changes price. 1 single cost for all users, no exception. I tagged as ubercart, paypal as well in case of there will be no other solution than these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this module list](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/authorize.net?filters=type%3Aproject_project) on Drupal.org. Drupal.org has advanced searching, which allows you to easily find the modules you need.

I found a few modules on the list, that looks like they could fit your need, but I'll give you the whole list and let you check them out and decide for yourself.

Comment: Agreed, you should be able to do this using an authorize.net gateway and use some non-complex method of passing the cost over. The search results on that link look promising.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/authorizenetwebform this looks good! I could not think of any possible authorize.net dedicated payment module :/ thanks a lot!